# CakePHP images and JS throwing 404

Tags: php, cakephp

I moved my CakePHP website from dev to production and now receiving 404 errors on images and JS files.

App is located in the `/var/www/html` folder and cake being in `/var/www/cake`.

example.com/webroot/images/logo.gif works fine but example.com/images/logo.gif throws a 404.

This is my **/var/www/html/.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your /var/www/html/webroot/.htaccess file look like?

Comment: @Stiliyan it looks like this - https://gist.github.com/tcope25/6e2f4e6eb4b0446e3e8d9dc455fd7778

Comment: @Stiliyan i removed those lines and it gave me a 403 forbidden.

Comment: On a second look, the looks unrelated to the directives in /webroot/.htaccess. What does the /var/www/.htaccess file look like?

Comment: CakePHP 2.x I guess? Please always name the exact version your question is related to... thank you.